# How can i fetch data from Google play in my app?

Tags: android, google-play-services, versioning

I have an android app, i want to check for version code of it from Google play. please suggest some way to do this. Don't answer with MarketServiceApi and its link unless you have explored it by yourself. i have already done research on it and got nothing, but if it is working for you then suggest the procedure to use it.

Comment: The people usually put a code in a simple html or txt in App Engine or other free and reliable service to check it when the app launches. You can get the version or whatever you want to put in.

Comment: @CaptainTeemo ya i have done that way but every time I update my apk i have to update my html service also, that's why i am looking for the way which gets updated by itself. and this can happen only by reading the data from Google play.

Comment: Also you can check the google play web page of your app and look for this tag inside the page. But you must think about the HTML can be changed at any moment by Google.
`<div class="content" itemprop="softwareVersion"> 1.1.4  </div>`